# Locating Cloudera Manager HDFS config files

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, cloudera-manager

I've installed a cluster via Cloudera Manager, and now I need to launch the cluster manually.

I've been using the following command:

```
$ sudo -u hdfs hadoop namenode / datanode / jobtracker
```

But then the `dfs.name.dir` is set up `/tmp`.  I can't seem to find where cloudera manager has the HDFS config files.  The ones in `/usr/lib/hadoop-02*/conf` seem to be minimal.  They're missing the `dfs.name.dir` which is what I'm looking for particularly.  I'm on an RHLE 6 system, by the way.  Being lazy, I though I could just copy over cloudera manager's HDFS config files, so I don't have to manually create them, the copy them over to 6 nodes :)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using CentOS 6.5, the Cloudera Manager special files do not show up in a SEARCH FILES result because their permissions are set to hide from all but the 'hdfs' user. In addition, there are multiple versions of hdfs-site.xml on the local drive some of which have partial amounts of real settings. The actual settings file is in the DATANODE folder not the NAMENODE folder as evidenced by the lack of dfs.datanode.data.dir values in the latter.

Answer (score 5):

I was facing same problem. 
I was changing configuration parameters from cloudera manager ui but was clueless where my changes were getting updated on local file system.

I ran grep command and found out that in my case configuration were stored at  /var/run/cloudera-scm-agent/process/***-hdfs-NAMENODE directory.

So David is right, whenever we change configs from ui and restart service, it creates new config. settings in /var/run/cloudera-scm-agent/process/ directory.

Comment: Note that this is also nicely described in the [Cloudera blog](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/07/how-does-cloudera-manager-work/).

Answer (score 2):

Cloudera manager deploying config file each time you start cluster, each time in different directory. Directories are named after process id or something like this. 
The configuration is passed explicitly to each deamon as parameter. So if you will look into command line of each hadoop deamons you can see where is configuration sitting (or just grep over disk for hdfs-site.xml. Names of config files are the same as usual.

Answer (score 1):

I was in the same boat and found this answer:

> To allow Hadoop client users to work with the HDFS, MapReduce, YARN
>   and HBase services you created, Cloudera Manager generates client
>   configuration files that contain the relevant configuration files with
>   the settings from your services. These files are deployed
>   automatically by Cloudera Manager based on the services you have
>   installed, when you add a service, or when you add a Gateway role on a
>   host.
>
> You can download and distribute these client configuration files
>   manually to the users of a service, if necessary.
>
> The Client Configuration URLs command on the cluster Actions menu
>   opens a pop-up that displays links to the client configuration zip
>   files created for the services installed in your cluster. You can
>   download these zip files by clicking the link.
>
> See Deploying Client Configuration Files for more information on this
>   topic.

On our system I got there via `http://your_server:7180/cmf/services/status` and clicked the Actions popup under the Add Cluster button. Hope that helps.